# How can I calculate the click rate (click/pageview) from this data frame?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to calculate the click-through rate (click/pageview) from the data frame below. The event column has the 'click' and 'pageview events'.
[image]

The event column contains 3 different categorical variables.

What I want to do is to find the total occurrences of the 'click' and 'pageview' events in the event column, then divide the total clicks by the total pageview to get the click rate

Desired output:

The output I want is a single decimal value. For example:
the sum of all the click / sum of all the pageview  = 70.0456

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Answer (score 0):

Hi derivated from you sql sample

Just summing you clicks and pageview should do the trick

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(A.click as FLOAT64)) / sum(CAST(B.pageview AS FLOAT64))
FROM    
(SELECT linkid, COUNT(1) click
      FROM table
      WHERE event ='click'
      GROUP BY linkid
) A

INNER JOIN 
(SELECT linkid, COUNT(1) pageview
FROM  table
WHERE event ='pageview' 
GROUP BY linkid) B ON A.linkid = B.linkid
```